# Is it better to define relationships in data source view or in Database?

Tags: ssas

I'm trying to combine couple of cubes to create a single cube, and there are lots of relationships defined In Data source view. Now 'm thinking to define the relationships in database level. I'm trying to understand this change from performance point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Relationships in the DSV* have **no** performance impact. They serve two purposes:

- Documentation on table structure, and
- helping some Wizards in BIDS to generate some code.

The latter is the case e. g. for the following cases: The Cube Wizard can suggest which tables are fact tables and hence will be the base of measure groups, and which are dimension tables. Furthermore, relationships in the Cube Designer tab "Dimension Usage" are generated based on the DSV relationships without you having to define them manually. And the key attribute of dimensions is defined automatically in Dimension Designer to be the attribute based on the primary key column(s).

*Relationships in the relational database* can have a negative performance impact on writing to the tables, as they need to be checked for every insert, delete, and update which affects the columns that have these constraints.

Depending on the database system, they implicitly cause some indexes to be created, which may offer performance improvements in some reading operations. But most of the statements issued by Analysis Services during processing will not benefit.

However, the relationships may have a positive "performance impact" on developer/debugging performance, as they give early error messages exactly when the data is changed that would violate the constraints. On the other hand, you have to take care of them as they dictate the order in which you do deletes/inserts: delete values from referencing tables before the records in the referenced tables, insert in opposite order.